# Deploy react typescript Project on Heroku

Tags: heroku, react-tsx

How can I deploy a react typescript project on Heroku? can't seem to find any working build pack.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way using vercel, works great!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).